# Does the German embassy disclose visa information to the country (Russia)

Tags: visas, germany, long-stay-visas, privacy

My wife is going to apply for family reunification visa in the German embassy in Russia (I'm on Blue Card in Germany currently). And she's worried, that German Embassy might send some visa/residence permit information to the russian government, which might cause some trouble for her family. Is there any privacy statement of the embassy, to find out whether or not they send this information?

Comment: While I am almost certain the German government will not contact the Russian government about issuance of visas and residence permits in normal circumstances, are you aware that Russia has exit controls that her visa may become visible to Russian state agents at some point in any case?

Comment: Well, not that big of a problem, as she might leave the country with a stop through Armenia (which doesn't require you to show your travel pasport). But anyways, thanks for the answer. Couldn't find any related documents though

Comment: If you have a foreign residence/citizenship while being a Russian citizen in Russian Federation, it does make sense to post the notification about that as required by law.  Why take a risk by not doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any privacy statement of the embassy, to find out whether or not they send this information?

Since all (short/long-term and transit) visas (‘uniform visa’) are entered into the VIS system and Article 3(3) excludes making such information to a 3d countries available, you may assume that the application and it's result is **not** shared with any other country that does not participate in the VIS system.

Exceptions exist for the 'prevention and detection of terrorist offences'.

---

> **Visa Information System (VIS)**
> **Article 3**
> ...
> 3. Data obtained from the VIS pursuant to the Decision referred to in paragraph 2 **shall not be transferred or made available to a third country** or to an international organisation. ...
> ...